# make certain creation between form and field in database in laravel

Tags: laravel, view, controller, request, field

want to produce data exclusive to some field in database, so i add them in my view create . but there is an error `cannot be null`. even though the field is nullable.

this my view `form.blade.php`

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Project *</label>        
        <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="project_id">
            <option>Select One</option>
            @foreach($projects as $id => $project)
              <option value="{{$id}}">{{$project}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Story # Meeting Name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_story">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Category *</label>
        <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="task_category">
            <option>Select One</option>
            @foreach($task_categories as $task_category)
              <option value="{{$task_category->task_category}}">{{$task_category->task_category}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Estimated *</label>                  
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estimated_time">
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="box-footer">
      <a href="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-12" style="border-radius : 0px;">SAVE</button>
      </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

this my request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'project_id',
        'task_category',
        'estimated_time',
        'spent_time' => 'nullable',
        'user_story' => 'nullable', 
        'story/meeting_name' => 'nullable',
        'assign' => 'nullable',
        'percentage' => 'nullable',
        'lateness' => 'nullable',
        'index' => 'nullable',
    ];
}
```

this my controller

```
public function store(OngoingRequest $request)
{
    // dd($request->all());
    $spentime = SpentTime::create([
        'project_id' => request('project_id'),
        'user_story' => request ('user_story'),
        'task_category' => request('task_category'),
        'estimated_time' => request('estimated_time'),  

        'spent_time' => request('spent_time'),                     
        'assign' => request('assign'),
        'story/meeting_name' => request('story/meeting_name'),
        'percentage'=> request('percentage'),
        'lateness' => request('lateness'),
        'index'=> request('index'),           
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('plan.index');
}
```

and the error :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqeLW.png)

fields that i don't want to fill and not in the form must be filled. but im not need that.

Comment: where are you validating rules? and show the migration for this table.

Comment: I use `Request` laravel. and it just include that request in controller

Answer (score 0):

set `spent_time` filed default value other wise set a nullable value

```
$table->string('spent_time')->nullable();

$table->boolean('spent_time')->default(0);
```

Comment: is this in the same file migration.?